# Pulling constants out of a summation

Tags: summation

Is there anyway I can pull x out of this summation to solve for it?

$$ 0 = \frac{-2}{N} \sum_i^N a_i(b_i - (xa_i))$$

EDIT: Thanks for all the quick comments guys.

I am confused by a certain step everyone seems to be taking.

$$ -\sum_i^N xa_i^2 = -x\sum_i^N a_i^2 $$

Can someone explain or link me to somewhere that explains how this is true.

Comment: Answers handle the $x$, but I'll note that you can remove the $-2/N$ factor out front. (Just divide through on both sides of the equation.)

Answer (score 10):

given

$$0 = \dfrac{-2}{N} \sum_i^N a_i(b_i - (xa_i))$$

$0=\dfrac{-2}{N} \sum_i^N(a_ib_i-xa_i^2)$

$0=\dfrac{-2}{N} \big (\sum_i^Na_ib_i-\sum_i^Nxa_i^2)$

$0=\dfrac{-2}{N} \big (\sum_i^Na_ib_i-x\sum_i^Na_i^2)$

*EDIT*
:
Here, we treat $x$ as a constant. Hence it can be 'pulled' out of the summation

For example :

$2+4+6=12$

$2(1+2+3)=12$

here, $2$ being a constant can be 'pulled' out from the summation

Comment: Thanks that makes sense now. I feel I lose all common sense when I see a summation.

Comment: happy to help:)

Comment: @Ian: Perhaps your common sense will return when you accept that summations are *summations*. Although the $\Sigma$ notation is sometimes scary-looking, it only serves to abbreviate expressions of *addition*, which is one of the least-scary operations we have! So, things like the Distributive Property and factoring-out constants work exactly as you expect.

Comment: @stilllearning, please accept an answer if you think it is satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The sum is $\sum_{i=1}^N a_ib_i-x\sum_{i=1}^N a_i^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You can, with a bit of work. We have
$$
\sum_i^Na_i(b_i-xa_i) = \sum_i^N(a_ib_i-xa_i^2) = \sum_i^Na_ib_i-x\sum_i^N a_i^2
$$
and from there it's easy.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a question:

This looks like the summations involved
when you are fitting a
straight line through the origin
to a set of data points
by least squares.
Is that what you are trying to do?

If you are learning about least squares
and other types of fitting,
you will be doing a $lot$ of summations,
and you will need to get comfortable
with them.